# How to add one blank after period

Tags: python, regex

There is a sentence. How to add one blank after period by regex in Python, between 'glabrous' and 'fruit'.
I try re.sub, but still have no idea.

sent1 = 'pistils 1.7 mm long, glabrous.fruit ellipsoid'

to

sent2 = 'pistils 1.7 mm long, glabrous. fruit ellipsoid'

Comment: You don't need regex just `sent1.replace(".", ". ")`

Comment: But this action will affect 1.7 mm

Comment: So you only wish to add space after dot in case there is some word before and some word after the dot and not a number?

Comment: Yes! You got my question. Really appreciate answer me. This is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it `re.sub('\.(?!\s|\d|$)', '. ', sent1)`